# getting large negative number for MySQL to_days

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, hikaricp

The following TO_DAYS statement is returning a very large, **negative** values such as -3.9084128648E11

```
SELECT...,
    s.enroll_start as enrollStart,
    TO_DAYS(s.enroll_start) as enrollStartToDays 
FROM...
WHERE...
```

s. enroll_start is a MySQL DATE data type.
The results look like (note that

```
enrollStart:2019-02-01 12:00 AM,
enrollStartDays:-3.9084128648E11
```

and I see similar results when trying to do a DATEDIFF between enrollStart and curdate(). `'21474836521' in column '39' is outside valid range for the datatype INTEGER`

What is especially odd is that this problem never occurs when running the query via Navicat or SQL Explorer.  It only happens within the webapps and even then doesn't occur consistently.

Comment: Cast enroll_start to date() if it's not already

Comment: MYSQL date columns are stored in format yyyy-mm-dd  so what datatype are you using?

Comment: s.enroll_start is DATE datatype.    My original results example was probably confusing because I had formatted the output via java SimpleDateFormat.getInstance(..)

Comment: HMM if its a date datatype it can't store a time - are you sure its not datetime or varchar or is java adding the time?

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. `select to_days('2019-02-01')` => 737456  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=5205c509278903a60ed297d2cee1890a Perhaps it's in how you're interpreting the result?

Comment: it throws an exception when I try to get the int value of the TO_DAYS from the resultset (rs.getInt("enrollStartToDays").    

To demonstrate the output i am doing this:
String enrollStartToDays = Double.toString(rs.getDouble("enrollStartToDays"));
And the value of enrollStartToDays is enrollStartDays:-3.9084128648E11

The time portion of the enrollStart is just because I'm doing something similar to show that value:
String enrollStart = SimpleDateFormat.getInstance().format(r.getDate("enrollStart"));
And java shows a default midnight time